# CREATE VIEW specifies more column names than columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

If I run the following statements in PostgreSQL 9.4.8, I get this error message:

> CREATE VIEW specifies more column names than columns.

But why? Doesn't `f1` return a table with 5 columns and shouldn't `v1` have 5 columns as well? Also, If I remove the casts from the first `SELECT` statement, I get this error message:

> Final statement returns unknown instead of character varying at column 1.

But why? The correct type `VARCHAR(20)` is known from `RETURNS`, so why is there no implicit cast of strings such as `'a'`?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1 (a1 INTEGER, a2 INTEGER)
RETURNS TABLE (c1 VARCHAR(20), c2 VARCHAR(20), c3 INTEGER, c4 VARCHAR(20), c5 VARCHAR(128))
AS $$
SELECT 'a'::VARCHAR(20), 'b'::VARCHAR(20), 1::INTEGER, 'c'::VARCHAR(20), 'd'::VARCHAR(128);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE VIEW v1 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
AS SELECT f1 (1, 2);
```

Comment: `... select * from f1 (1, 2);` Your variant returns the single column of the `record` type (just try it without creating a view).

Comment: @Abelisto Excellent, if you want to turn this comment into an answer, I shall accept it. Thx in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the simple example:

```
postgres=# create function foofunc() returns table(a int, b text) language sql as $$ select 1, 'a'::text $$;
postgres=# select foofunc();
╔═════════╗
║ foofunc ║
╠═════════╣
║ (1,a)   ║
╚═════════╝
```

When a function called in the column/variable context it returns the single value of the returning type specified. Here is the source of the error: the view's `select` returns only one column.

However if function called in the table context then it returns the values like a true table:

```
postgres=# select * from foofunc();
╔═══╤═══╗
║ a │ b ║
╠═══╪═══╣
║ 1 │ a ║
╚═══╧═══╝
```

So you should to use the second approach when you creating the view:

```
CREATE VIEW v1 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) AS
  SELECT * FROM f1 (1, 2);
```

Comment: Thx & FYI: I have posted a [follow-up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794976/error-column-specified-more-than-once) question.