# "ERROR: column ... specified more than once" in VIEW definition

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, sql-view, set-returning-functions

This is a follow-up question to an [earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793734/create-view-specifies-more-column-names-than-columns/38794591). I have a stored function `f1` that takes two arguments returns a table with 5 columns; for now the returned values are constant, later they will be calculated from the arguments.

I also have a table `t1` with two columns that correspond in type to `f1`'s arguments.

I would now like to define a view `v1` that contains the union of all rows returned from `f1` for all argument pairs stored in `t1`. For the given example values the result should be:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 3 | a | b | 1 | c | d |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 4 | 5 | a | b | 1 | c | d |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If the first two columns are stripped of, that would be fine as well. Notice that `f1` could return several rows for certain argument values.

I've tried the following statement, but it gives me this error message:

> ```
> ERROR: column "c4" specified more than once
> ```

```
CREATE VIEW v1 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
AS SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT c1, c2 FROM t1) AS x,
  f1 (x.c1, x.c2);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here are the preceding statements to set the example up:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1 (a1 INTEGER, a2 INTEGER)
RETURNS TABLE (c1 VARCHAR(20), c2 VARCHAR(20), c3 INTEGER, c4 VARCHAR(20), c5 VARCHAR(128))
AS $$
SELECT 'a'::VARCHAR(20), 'b'::VARCHAR(20), 1::INTEGER, 'c'::VARCHAR(20), 'd'::VARCHAR(128);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INTEGER, c2 INTEGER);
INSERT INTO t1 (c1, c2)
VALUES (2,3), (4,5);

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS v1;
```

Comment: Don't use `select *` -- instead select the fields you need.  As is, `c1` exists in both `f1` and `t1`...

Comment: @sgeddes I'll try that, but the error message quotes `c4`. Excellent PostgreSQL answers here, BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a `LATERAL` join in the `SELECT` query:

```
CREATE VIEW v1 AS
SELECT f.*
FROM   t1
     , f1 (t1.c1, t1.c2) AS f;  -- implicit CROSS JOIN LATERAL
```

Since the column names defined in the function definition already match what you want, you can also drop the column names from view definition.

Creating a view works with *early binding* anyway. Meaning, only columns selected at creation time are included in the view. If you later change the function definition to return an additional column, then that's *not* included in the view. (If you remove or rename columns, you break the view.)

You *could* also include the set-returning function `f1(..)` in the `SELECT` list, to *almost* the same effect. The differences:

- Set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list violate the SQL standard and are frowned upon by some. Also not portable to some other RDBMS. Since Postgres introduced (standard SQL) `LATERAL` with Postgres 9.3, that's generally preferable.
- A set-returning function in the `SELECT` list (effectively a correlated subquery) is the equivalent of `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true`, i.e. it preserves all rows of `t1`, even where the function does not return any rows. `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` like above *removes* rows where `f1()` does not return rows.
- You *can* decompose the well-defined row type returned from the function with `SELECT (f1(...)).*, ...`, but the function may be evaluated repeatedly for each column in the return type instead of once only.

Related and more details:

- [Split function-returned record into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297935/split-function-returned-record-into-multiple-columns/38297985#38297985)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)