# Final statement returns unknown instead of character varying

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Here is a yet unanswered second part of an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793734/create-view-specifies-more-column-names-than-columns/38794591) as a separate question:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1 (a1 INTEGER, a2 INTEGER)
RETURNS TABLE (c1 VARCHAR(20), c2 VARCHAR(20), c3 INTEGER, c4 VARCHAR(20), c5 VARCHAR(128))
AS $$
SELECT 'a'::VARCHAR(20), 'b'::VARCHAR(20), 1::INTEGER, 'c'::VARCHAR(20), 'd'::VARCHAR(128);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

This sample code is meant to create a function `f1` that returns a table with a single row of 5 columns.

If I remove the casts from the `SELECT` statement, I get this error message:

> Final statement returns unknown instead of character varying at column 1.

But are the casts really necessary? It would seem that the correct type `VARCHAR(20)` is known from `RETURNS`, so why is there no implicit cast of strings such as `'a'`? Is there a better way to formulate such things in a concise way?

Comment: Any reason you aren't just using `TEXT`? I believe that would also resolve the implicit type conversion for you.

Comment: postgres does not know if you don't try to select 'a'::int or 'a'::float or anything else is next rows or so => type is `unknown`

Comment: Some relatively old discussion about this: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/183.1302200970%40sss.pgh.pa.us